# How to grep a line followed by a newline from output in terminal

Tags: bash, grep, gentoo

I have the following output on my terminal

```
* These packages depend on app-portage/gentoolkit-0.6.5:

 * These packages depend on app-portage/getuto-1.11:
sys-apps/portage-3.0.63 (!build ? app-portage/getuto)

 * These packages depend on app-portage/portage-utils-0.96.1:
app-admin/perl-cleaner-2.31 (!pkgcore ? app-portage/portage-utils)
```

How do I only grep lines such as `gentoolkit` that have no lines following it?

What I have tried : `some command | xargs grep -eF ".*\n\n"`
But this returns `File or Directory not found`.

What I am trying to achieve?
In gentoo linux, `eix-installed -a | xargs equery depends` gives the dependency for all packages. I want to find the ones that have no dependencies listed.

Comment: Just use `qdepends -Q`.

Comment: `eix-installed -a | xargs -r sh -c 'for __; do qdepends -QqqC "$__" >/dev/null || echo "$__"; done' --`

Comment: @jhnc Like what things?  If you worry about other possible errors that may cause nonerror exit code I agree, but this should suffice for immediate use.

Comment: @konsolebox I mean that when I ran it, it gave packages that `equery depends` says other packages depend on

Comment: @jhnc Perhaps you can share an example output of an equery command targettng a package and another `qdepends -Q` command targetting the same package but with contrasting outputs.

Comment: @konsolebox app-eselect/eselect-iptables-20220320 is one example (but the equery output looks wrong); dev-libs/gmp-6.3.0-r1 is another (but qdepends looks wrong). I don't know much about gentoo; maybe down to the version number being included?

Comment: @jhnc I have `app-eselect/eselect-iptables-20220320` installed.  `equery d app-eselect/eselect-iptables`, `equery d app-eselect/eselect-iptables-20220320`, and `equery d app-eselect/eselect-iptables-20220320::gentoo` for me shows no output after `* These packages depend on app-eselect/eselect-iptables[-20220320]:` besides the irrelevant error message I mentioned earlier in your answer.  `qdepends -Q` always shows `qdepends: no matches found for your query`.  Commands against `dev-libs/gmp` OTOH show output.

Comment: @konsolebox net-firewall/iptables-1.8.10 depends on app-eselect/eselect-iptables-20220320 (equery doesn't list; qdepends does); dev-lib/gmp-6.3.0-r1 (output from eix-installed) shows nothing for me for qdepends but does if I leave out the version

Comment: @jhnc I see the problem.  The answer is simply because I was using an older version of `qdepends` and `qdepends` now respects IDEPEND dependencies of a package but `equery d` (v0.6.5) still doesn't which I suspect is the version you have if you unmasked the keyword, or v0.6.3-r1.  The bleeding edge version (9999) however shows output.  Try updating to it.

Comment: @konsolebox hopefully that's useful to the OP. I don't actually use gentoo normally, just installed a container for debugging the awk code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although @oguz-ismail's answer would work with the sample output provided, it seems that actual `equery` output becomes garbled when it is fed into a pipe.

This convoluted commandline seems to work around the problems:

```
</dev/null script -B /dev/null -f -q -c '
    eix-installed -a | xargs equery depends
' |
tr -d '\r' |
grep -v '^---' |
awk '!/\n/' RS=
```

- `script` makes `equery` believe it is writing to a terminal

  - redirecting `script`'s stdin from `/dev/null` avoids some display oddities (cf. [re-enable on-screen carriage return behaviour without including them in the data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78243238/re-enable-on-screen-carriage-return-behaviour-without-including-them-in-the-data))
- `tr` strips the carriage returns added by `script`
- `grep` filters some non-dependency info (per @konsolebox comment)
- `awk` splits on empty lines and filters out multi-line records

Comment: If you got it, that is worth an upvote.

Comment: `equery` unfortunately sends error messages after an empty package entry like this: `* These packages depend on x/y:
--- Unmatched removal atom(s) in /etc/portage/profile/package.mask: ...`; causing such packages to also be not included.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need something a bit longer. Something that stores lines ending in `':'` and then checks, in some way, that the line that follows is empty (with `awk` simply checking `NF` works). You also need a trigger to indicate no output is waiting. Setting the variable holding the saved line to empty works.

There are many ways to do this, but you can translate the above into:

```bash
awk '/:$/ {last=$0; next} NF==0 && length(last) { print last } { last="" } END { if (length(last)) print }'
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using a heredoc to feed data (you can just pipe to it as you are doing), and making sure you catch a final line of interest in the `END` rule, you can do:

```
$ awk '/:$/ {last=$0; next} NF==0 && length(last) { print last } { last="" } END { if (length(last)) print }' << eof
>  * These packages depend on app-portage/gentoolkit-0.6.5:
>
>  * These packages depend on app-portage/getuto-1.11:
> sys-apps/portage-3.0.63 (!build ? app-portage/getuto)
>
>  * These packages depend on app-portage/portage-utils-0.96.1:
> app-admin/perl-cleaner-2.31 (!pkgcore ? app-portage/portage-utils)
>
>  * These packages depend on app-portage/cockatoolkit-0.6.5:
> eof
 * These packages depend on app-portage/gentoolkit-0.6.5:
 * These packages depend on app-portage/cockatoolkit-0.6.5:
```

(`"cockatoolkit"` was just made up for the example...)

Look things over and let me know if you have problems.

Comment: `equery` produces very strange output that somehow mixes up line ordering when fed into a pipe. it's why @oguz-ismail's answer didn't work

Comment: Oooh. It shouldn't as `awk` just reads lines, but I'm concerned about the non ASCII characters involved. That's interesting. How is a pipe different from `stdin` from that standpoint? We are just tying `stdout` from the prior process to `stdin` of the current which should be have the same as a heredoc. Do you have an example I could try?

Comment: I'd vote for @oguz-ismail's answer because it too looks like it should work. Strange issue.

Comment: actually his answer didn't work because `equery` defaults to writing something entirely different when fed to a pipe unless `-N` is given, but even with, output gets garbled

Comment: I'll investigate further. Without sample data, I'm not sure how to adjust.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin even some mandatory POSIX tools modify their behavior based on where the output is going, e.g. try `ls` vs `ls | cat`. Thou shalt not parse the output of such commands :-).

Comment: Words of wisdom to live by. Thank you Ed! Funny how word-splitting gets sprinkled in in that case.