# re-enable on-screen carriage return behaviour without including them in the data stream

Tags: linux, tty, pty

Typically, when displaying data to screen, a newline is treated as if there is also a carriage return.

Consider:

```
$ printf "aaa\nbbb\n"
aaa
bbb
$ printf "aaa\nbbb\n" | od -c
0000000   a   a   a  \n   b   b   b  \n
0000010
$ printf "aaa\nbbb\n" | tr -d '\r'
aaa
bbb
$
```

Now:

```
$ script -B/dev/null -fqc 'printf "aaa\nbbb\n"'
aaa
bbb
$ script -B/dev/null -fqc 'printf "aaa\nbbb\n"' | od -c
0000000   a   a   a  \r  \n   b   b   b  \r  \n
0000012
$ script -B/dev/null -fqc 'printf "aaa\nbbb\n"' | tr -d '\r' | od -c
0000000   a   a   a  \n   b   b   b  \n
0000010
$
```

But:

```
$ script -B/dev/null -fqc 'printf "aaa\nbbb\n"' | tr -d '\r'
aaa
   bbb
      $ script -B/dev/null -fqc 'printf "aaa\nbbb\n"' | tr -d '\r' >log
$ od -c <log
0000000   a   a   a  \n   b   b   b  \n
0000010
$ cat log
aaa
bbb
$
```

What is happening in the `script` pipeline that causes different display behaviour for apparently-identical data?

Is there a simple-ish command that could be used in place of (or in addition to) `tr -d '\r'` in the `script` pipeline that would remove the extraneous carriage returns from the data stream while also re-enabling the normal `stty onlcr` display behaviour when the pipeline destination is the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementations of `script` I have checked ([util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/6ff6f5b6ffd9323cc568def2169225dd84bc3a0c/term-utils/script.c#L960) and [freebsd](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.bin/script/script.c#n235)), both call cfmakeraw(3) if their stdin is a terminal.

On linux, it is [specified](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib-cfmakeraw-3.html) that:

> The cfmakeraw() function shall set the attributes of the termios structure referenced by termios_p as follows:
>
> ```
> termios_p->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP
>                         |INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL|IXON);
> termios_p->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
> termios_p->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHONL|ICANON|ISIG|IEXTEN);
> termios_p->c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE|PARENB);
> termios_p->c_cflag |= CS8;
> ```

FreeBSD is [less specific](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cfmakeraw), saying:

> The cfmakeraw() function  sets the flags stored in the termios structure to a state disabling all input and output processing, giving a "raw I/O path"

---

To reverse these changes, calling `stty` with desired settings in an appropriate part of the pipeline (as per @philippe's answer), is one option.

Another way may be to avoid the changes happening in the first place, by redirecting stdin from a non-terminal (eg. `/dev/null`) so that cfmakeraw() is never called.
However, the util-linux documentation [warns](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/script.1.adoc#bugs) that running with stdin not connected to a terminal may cause problems in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

You see that behaviour because `script` disabled `opost`:

```
$ script -B/dev/null -fqc 'printf "aaa\nbbb\n"' | { stty opost < /dev/tty; tr -d '\r'; }
aaa
bbb
```

Comment: that's embarrassing. I thought I'd tried inserting `stty -a </dev/tty` in all places in the pipeline but it appears I somehow neglected the `</dev/tty` when I tried it in that position!